# Pop up auto-complete suggestion automatically?

Tags: autocompletion

Auto-complete window can be pop-ed up when I use `<C-N>`, could I set it to pop up automatically when input keyword exceeds some length (3 characters)? YCM can do this but I don't want to install it. Does the default completion support this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Automatic completion suggestions aren't built into Vim; plugins (like YouCompleteMe) implement this via `:autocmd CursorMovedI` triggers.

Another plugin is [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879); it purely implements the automatic suggestions. Unlike YCM, it doesn't offer additional completions or any other extensions, so that may be a good alternative to try if you don't want to install YCM.

Answer (score 4):

There is another nice plugin called `mucomplete` (https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete) that shows automatically a popup with completion suggestions.